# Date_Histogram in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Today I had a task where I have to aggregate the data bucketed by 1 hour interval. So I used Date_Histogram aggregation in elastic search. Below is the query:

```
GET test-2017.02.01/_search
{
  "size" : 0,

  "aggs": {
    "range_aggs": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "hour",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I got the below result:

```
    "aggregations": {
    "range_aggs": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-02-01 12:00",
          "key": 1485950400000,
          "doc_count": 4027
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-02-01 13:00",
          "key": 1485954000000,
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Every is good till now as I have run this query for one day, but when I run the query for multiple days in that case, I am getting the keys per day. 
My question is - How can I get the data for the hour intervals(ex- 9am to 10am, 10am to 11am, ...etc) across all the days ?

Comment: Which version of ES r u using? I've tried to reproduce your problem with 5.2.1, but w/o success. Here is response I've got: https://github.com/pvasilyev/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/main/resources/elasticsearch/date-histogram-in-elastic-search/response.json. Looks like the hour-span is working by default.

Comment: I am using 2.3, I need response grouped by hour, on across days,

Comment: I've tried 2.3.5 and the same result - it is just working out of the box. Could you please share the way how to reproduce your problem? Are you sure the problem is related to ES?

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
  "aggs": {
    "range_aggs": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "range_aggs": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "hour"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need response grouped by hour, on across days, try this one.